# Handsontable context menu item "type"

Tags: javascript, contextmenu, handsontable

I'm trying to create a handsontable context menu with different types. This site is linked to from the handsontable docs (for 0.16.1) http://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/docs/items.html however it doesn't seem to be working (code below). The context menu has two main items, and when I click on Font Size, the console logs its name but doesn't act like an input.

```
contextMenu:  {
    callback: function (key, options) {
        console.log(key);
    },
    items: {
        "status": {
            name: 'Status',
            submenu: {
                items: [{
                    key: 'status:pnc',
                    name: 'Private and Confidential'
                },
                {
                    key: 'status:fxd',
                    name: 'Fixed'
                }]
            },
        },
        "fontsize": {
            name: "Font Size",
            type: 'text',
            value: '14',
            events: {
                keyup: function(e) {
                    console.log(e.keycode);
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the console.log works in chrome if i use your definition. I do see a broken submenu. If you look at the documentation a submenu you see the syntax is a bit different. You dont define an array, just another items object definition.

```
contextMenu: {
  callback: function(key, options) {
    console.log(key);
  },
  items: {
    "status": {
      name: 'Status',
      submenu: {
        items: {
           {
              key: 'status:pnc',
              name: 'Private and Confidential'
            }, 
            {
              key: 'status:fxd',
              name: 'Fixed'
            }
        }
      },
    },
    "fontsize": {
      name: "Font Size",
      type: 'text',
      value: '14',
      events: {
        keyup: function(e) {
          console.log(e.keycode);
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
```

See: http://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo/sub-menus.html

When i fixed the submenu, i and no problems with the fontsize item being shown as an input.

Comment: The submenu menu works with the code above, but the "font size" menu won't display as a input text field.

Comment: I really had no problem with the input when i tried with the correct code. The console logs trigger and its just an input.